# Underlying implementation of Group By clause in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What is the underlying implementation of Group By clause in Spark SQL? I understand that Spark supports two types of Group by operations underneath i.e. GroupByKey and ReduceByKey. ReduceByKey is a map side reduce and provides better performance over GroupByKey.

In our application code, we use Spark SQL on Spark Dataframes and we are not creating RDDs directly. So, I had this question in mind whether GroupBy in Spark SQL does a GroupByKey or ReduceByKey or something else.

Answer (score 5):

In Spark SQL, if you call `groupBy(key).agg(...)` with some aggregation function inside `agg`, the typical physical plan is HashAggregate -> Exchange -> HashAggregate. The first `HashAggregate` is responsible for doing partial aggregation (locally on each executor), then the `Exchange` represents shuffle and then the second `HashAggregate` represents the final aggregation (final merge) after the shuffle.

Also notice, that sometimes `HashAggregate`s might be replaced by `SortAggregate`s or `ObjectHashAggregate`s depending on the aggregation function and data types of aggregated columns, but the pattern stays the same (they come in pairs and there is `Exchange` in between).

Also sometimes the `Exchange` might be missing (there is no shuffle), if the data was repartition in advance (perhaps from bucketing or from some previous aggregation and so on).

Comment: Thanks David for this information. Could you please provide me some documentation links on this front from Apache Spark. Looks like I am interested in reading this further.

Comment: @Prashant You are welcome. As far as I know, this Spark internals are not very well documented. I myself get this information directly from Spark source code (and also from practice).

Comment: Where do you read about spark code? Also, is there a way to quickly get a hang of it at high level? ( I know my question is quite generic).

Comment: @Prashant Spark source code is available at github https://github.com/apache/spark (it is an open source project). It is written mostly in Scala (partly also in Java and Python). It may take some time to get through it, but it depends on your background.

Comment: So it appears it does aggregate the data locally before shuffling, similar to ReduceByKey,  so performance shuouldn't be a concern